# tabs when editing node in admin - using Seven theme

Tags: tabs, drupal-7, themes, admin

I am using the Seven theme and wondered if there was anything that can be done about he vertical tabs at the bottom to either hide the ones my user does not need or make them look a bit nicer.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change which tabs show up for which roles, use the Override Node Options module: https://www.drupal.org/project/override_node_options
To change the look, you could create a custom module that adds CSS and/or JS in hook_init(). Another way to change the look would be to make a subtheme of Seven, set that as your admin theme, and then add your CSS / JS in the new theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate which ones appear by proper use of `hook_form_alter`.

For that, you will need to create a small module, implement the hook, and then hide any element you want by setting `$element['#access'] = false;`

As an example, assuming you are interested in the node form for content type `dummy_type`:

In `mymodule.module`:

```
<?php
   function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state,$form_id) {
     if($form_id=='dummy_type_node_form') {
        $form['additional_settings']['#access'] = false;
     }
   }
```

The above snippet will hide all the core vertical tabs. You can pick the specific ones you want by playing around a bit.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you need to create role and assign permission

Step 1 : Create new role go to following path
Administration » People » Permissions

Here add new role e.g. content manager.

Step 2 : Click on edit permission as newly created role.

Here assign role as per your requirement.